# For different possible Monad instances of a type, is the implied Functor instance always the same?

Tags: haskell, monads, functor, free-theorem

According to the [Typeclassopedia](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Typeclassopedia) and [this link](http://article.gmane.org/gmane.comp.lang.haskell.libraries/15384) a type can only have a single `Functor` instance (there's a proof in the link). But it is my understanding that it is possible for a given type to have multiple possible `Monad` instances, is this right? But for a given `Monad` instance there is a free `Functor` instance with

```
fmap f xs  =  xs >>= return . f
```

From this, I conclude that if I stumble upon a type in which I can define multiple `Monad` instances in different ways, then the `fmap` function derived as above must equal for all of them, in other words, if I have two pairs of functions:

```
bind_1 :: m a -> (a -> m b) -> m b
unit_1 :: a -> m a

bind_2 :: m a -> (a -> m b) -> m b
unit_2 :: a -> m a
```

for the same type constructor `m`, than, necessarily:

```
xs `bind_1` (unit_1 . f) == xs `bind_2` (unit_2 . f)
```

for all `xs :: a` and `f :: a -> b`.

Is this true? Does this hold as a theorem?

Comment: (You'll certainly need to assume that both instances obey the monad laws.)

Comment: Reasoning: The proof you reference assumes that the candidate alternative functor `fmap'` satisfies `fmap' id = id`. (They call `fmap'` `foo`.) This is not true in general, for example: `fmap' f xs = map f (take 4 xs)`.

Comment: @enoughreptocomment: Sure it's true in general.  `fmap id = id` is one of the properties required to be a functor.

Comment: I would be interested to see a type with two different monad instances.

Comment: Note that the "free functor instance" is an illusion. Actually, you need the functor instance to start with for the monad laws to even make sense; indeed the "more fundamental" operation on monads is `join` which does by itself not imply an `fmap` implementation (but needs one to be useful). Only by historical accident (and preference for _practical usefulness & efficiency) has it come about that `Monad` does not ([yet](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Functor-Applicative-Monad_Proposal)) have `Functor` as superclass, and has `>>=` but not `join` as a method.

Comment: @TomEllis: there was a dedicated question for that. A good example is the [`Omega` monad](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/control-monad-omega-0.3.1/docs/Control-Monad-Omega.html), which is basically nothing but a list with more sophisticated `Monad` instance.

Comment: @leftaroundabout: "Warning: Omega is only a monad when the results of runOmega are interpreted as a set"  So I don't believe it!

Comment: @leftaroundabout: Rafael means that there is a function of type `Monad f => (a -> b) -> f a -> f b` that satisfies the same conditions as `fmap`.

Comment: @TomEllis I think you missed my point, which was that you have to assume the laws are true for both instances. The laws themselves aren't true in general, they're only true for instances that satisfy them. It's possible, as per my example, to make an instance which doesn't. I was pointing out you'd need a valid monad, rather than simply an instance of the datatype. Of course they're true for every _valid_ instance. You'll notice that jozefg used the monad laws rather than simply the types; I was pointing out that this would be necessary.

Comment: @TomEllis: true, `Omega` is a bad example, it doesn't seem possible with lists at all. But for a simple example that's obviously fine, consider `Writer` with each `mappend` flipped.

Comment: @leftaroundabout: Nice example.  Indeed any differing `Monoid` instances on the same type will give rise to different `Monad` instances.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Yes. In fact we can make the stronger statement that all function with the type

```
fmap :: (a -> b) -> (F a -> F b)
```

such that `fmap id = id` are equivalent. This actually just falls out of the type of `fmap` with something called parametricity.

In your case, if `>>=` and `return` satisfy the monad laws, then

```
 mFmap f a  = a >>= return . f
 mFmap id a = a >>= return . id
 mFmap id a = a >>= return
 mFmap id a = a
 mFmap id = id
```

By the monad law that `a >>= return` is just `a`. Using this result, we can appeal to the free theorem we get from parametricity and we have our proof.